# Disable resharper 10 javascript features completely

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2015

Is there anyway to disable resharper 10 javascript features completely.

Comment: Go to `ReSharper - Options - Environment -> Products and Features` and disable `JS and TS feature`

Comment: There is so much options there, in resharper settings, its like a carnival theming, thanks a lot!!! BTW how do I mark your answer as correct?

Comment: I've posted it as answer, thank you too.

Answer (score 5):

Go to `ReSharper -> Options -> Environment -> Products and Features` and disable `JavaScript and TypeScript` feature.